# How to submit a form and get the desired result using python

Tags: python, python-requests, submit, urllib, form-submit

I am trying to get the geolocation data from the following website: https://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/, however it does not get the desired geolocation for the specific address

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import requests
params = {'address':'Any Address'}
search_url = 'https://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/?'
url = search_url + urlencode(params)
r = requests.get(url)
r.content
```

I also tried using requests.post but it does not give the correct geolocation data

```
import requests
url = "https://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/"
values = {'address':'Any Address'}
r = requests.post(url, params = values)
r.content
```

Comment: Do you want to submit this form? https://screenshots.firefox.com/Ft4QQvSpWb4TPYxj/www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com

Comment: Yes after submitting the form I want to scrape the longitude and latitude for the address